# Can't display the description of a list of sub categories

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories

I can't seem to display the description of a list of sub categories. So far I have this

```
<?php
 $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=5&hide_empty');
 foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  echo '<div style="position:relative;float:left;width:100%;margin:0 0 20px 0;border-bottom:1px dashed #cdcdcd;padding:0 0 20px 0">';
  echo sprintf('
   <a class="newstitle" href="%s" style="margin:0">%s</a>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
  echo '<br /><br />';
  echo '</div>';
 }
?>
```

This lists the sub categories' titles fine with the correct links but I can't seem to show the description under the two line breaks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like that.

```
<?php
 $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=5&hide_empty');
 foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory):?>
<div style="position:relative;float:left;width:100%;margin:0 0 20px 0;border-bottom:1px dashed #cdcdcd;padding:0 0 20px 0">
    <a class="newstitle" href="<?php echo get_category_link($subcategory->term_id) ?>" style="margin:0"><?php echo apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name) ?></a>
    <div class="cat-desc">
        <p>
            <?php echo category_description($subcategory->term_id); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br /><br />    
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```